# Xamarin PureSocketCluster Multiple Assemblies

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin

After adding the Package `PureSocketCluster` version 3.1.0 to my Xamarin project, I get the following error when compiling:

```
.../Projects/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.iOS/CSC: Error CS1703: 
Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported:    '.../.nuget/packages/system.reflection.emit/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.1/System.Reflection.Emit.dll'
and
'/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Reflection.Emit.dll'. 
Remove one of the duplicate references. (CS1703) (HelloWorld.iOS)
```

During the installation, I observed the following warnings:

```
Detected package downgrade: Xamarin.Forms from 3.4.0.1008975 to 3.1.0.697729. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
 HelloWorld.iOS (>= 1.0.0) -> HelloWorld (>= 1.0.0) -> Xamarin.Forms (>= 3.4.0.1008975) 
 HelloWorld.iOS (>= 1.0.0) -> Xamarin.Forms (>= 3.1.0.697729)
```

It's a very basic Hello World project, I just wanted to check if the communication with my socketcluster based websocket works in general.

[image]

I am using Visual Studio 2017 for Mac 7.6.11.
I'm fairly new to VS, so please don't kill me, if I made a stupid beginner mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to resolve the issue is to add this to the iOS project file.

```
<PackageReference Include="System.Reflection.Emit">
  <Version>4.3.0</Version>
  <ExcludeAssets>all</ExcludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

Of course you need to make sure the nuget package has been added to the iOS package first.
Here is a [similar issue](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/120814/xamarin-ios-project-cs1703-multiple-assemblies-with-equivalent-identity-have-been-imported) that you can refer.

Comment: I found that similar issue, but somehow it doesn't work for me. I added the package `System.Reflection.Emit` to the iOS project. Then I unloaded the project by right click > unload. Then I edited the project file by right click > Tools > Edit File. I added the `PackageReference` to an already present `ItemGroup`node under `<Project><PropertyGroup>`. I reloaded the project and cleaned it, then I built it, which results in the same error.

Comment: Delete the  folder bin and obj in iOS and Forms ,then clean and rebuild your project

Comment: Deleting both the bin and obj folders fixed it! Thanks @Lucas which begs the question: Whisky Tango Foxtrott Questionmark

Comment: Sure thing my friend! Thank you! But still: why is VS's "clean" not able to "clean" properly? What is this?